# Keep only the first element of a nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary

For example, is there a way to change

```
{'z': {'pl': 0.1001692265,
  'sa': 0.0899505839},
 'y': {'ap': 0.0734830126}}
```

Into

```
{'z': {'pl': 0.1001692265},
 'y': {'ap': 0.0734830126}}
```

I'm looking for a solution that would be dynamic and not just based on the value of the key in this case (i.e. 'sa')

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first key-value pair, with d as the original dictionary you can use:

```
# Using suggestion by Ch3steR
{k:dict([next(iter(v.items()))]) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Or using itertools.islice as suggesed by MechanicPig

```
{k:dict(itertools.islice(v.items(), 1)) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: Nice one. To get exact output: `{k:dict([next(iter(v.items()))]) for k, v in d.items()}`.

Comment: @Ch3steR `itertools.islice` maybe a better way.

Comment: @MechanicPig more readable too.

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.islice` is probably the most elegant way:

```
>>> dct = {'z': {'pl': 0.1001692265, 'sa': 0.0899505839}, 'y': {'ap': 0.0734830126}}
>>> {k: dict(islice(v.items(), 1)) for k, v in dct.items()}
{'z': {'pl': 0.1001692265}, 'y': {'ap': 0.0734830126}}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Python3.8+

In dict comprehension, we loop over outer dict. We can convert the inner dict to iterator and use `next` to get the first element. We can use the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions) to store the key.

```
{k: {(k1:=next(iter(v))): v[k1]} for k, v in d.items()}
# {'z': {'pl': 0.1001692265}, 'y': {'ap': 0.0734830126}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as the 'first element' of a dictionary. Python dictionaries are unordered.

If you need a dictionary like structure that maintains order, the `OrderedDict` type of Python's [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) library is an option.

Comment: In python3.6+, the dictionary guarantees the insertion order.

Comment: As the above mentioned, the order is preserved here so I always know that it's going to be the key-value pair in the nested dict with the highest value